# SQL Update query using variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing php to update a user's balance, but my UPDATE query seems to be throwing an error when it is executed.

```
    $student = $database->quote($_POST ["studentID"]);
    $amount = $database->quote($_POST ["update_balance"]);

    //sets query to update user balance
    $query = "UPDATE `User` SET `balance`= (`.$amount.`) WHERE `userID`= (`.$student.`)";
    //excecutes the query
    $database->exec($query);
```

The 'studentID' and 'update_balance' are names of input fields being captured in the HTML.

Comment: remove `(` and `) `before and after variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @zahraj added your fix , thanks for suggestion! :)

Answer (score 1):

remove  (`. things . and run sql query

```
$query = "UPDATE `User` SET `balance`= '$amount' WHERE `userID`= '$student'";
```

Comment: This fixes the issue of it the error being thrown, however it is updating the balance from 'NULL' to 0. The type is an int and the input tag has a type of "number". Could it possibly be passing the $amount through as a string and converting that to 0?

Comment: Apologies, i was referencing the wrong field in $amount. Should really check better before i ask silly questions.

Comment: your problem solved or no? if no echo your query and paste it here

Comment: @GeorgieLyme would you pleae mark this as a correct answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements as it's considered much safer than any string escaping mechanism:

```
$statement = $somePdoInstance->prepare("UPDATE user SET balance = :balance WHERE userId = :user_id");
$statement->execute(array(
   "balance" => $amount, // the values from POST
   "user_id" => $student
));
```

Now your update query should work fine and it's much safer.